# Detach Entity without EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa

For a test, I need to detach an entity, but I have no direct access to the EntityManager. So I cannot use something like:

```
em.detach(myEntity);
```

Is there another easy way to simply detach an entity? I do have access to my embedded EJBContainer.

Comment: Just create a new entity object (and sub-objects if needed, recursively) and copy all the properties from `myEntity` to it.

Comment: I don't think you can. Its the EntityManager that is responsible for maintaining its persistence context. If you can't access it, you can't manipulate the context. I would rather focus on how you CAN get access to the EntityManager rather than working around the fact that you don't have it.

Comment: Can you use JNDI to look up the EntityManager? Example here: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/ss141213/archive/2005/12/dont_use_persis_1.html

Comment: I'll probably have to do the lookup. The EntityManager resides inside the class I'm testing (as a protected member w/o getter/setter). I can access the member directly inside the test, but this always causes a NullPointerException, probably because the EM is injected by the container, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: A detached entity in JPA is generally an entity with non-null `@Id` field which is not managed by prestistance context. So actually @Abhinav is right.

Answer (score -2):

If your modify MyEntity and don't persist this change, the entity will be detached.

Regards

Comment: What are you talking about? Its JPA, the changes on a managed entity will be persisted when the transaction is committed. This is about manually detaching an entity, not about persisting anything.